# CSRF Risks and Tokens

Tags: php, jquery, json, jsonp, csrf

I have a bookmark that injects a form into another server's webpage. This form submits data back to my server via JSONP using jQuery, adding the submitted data to the database.

**Question:** This injected form also contains a CSRF token in a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="MWkgtQbdH6maJhuGL7ObwPcbgqARUCTjb4NSdo29">
```

Will this still pose a CSRF risk?

Comment: How are you generating the token?

Comment: Token is generated by my PHP framework and stored in the session cookie. http://laravel.com/docs/views/forms#csrf-protection

Answer (score 0):

The page can still be scraped and submitted remotely. It's a deterrent, but not an absolute solution. It will stop links, but someone could post the form remotely.

You could check the referrer as well, but some clients and firewalls prevent sending referrers.

One solution is to set a cookie via js on submit, then validate that server side.

Comment: Do you mean the site that the user uses my bookmark on can scrape the CSRF token in the form that was injected, and do the CSRF attack?

Comment: I guess I would have to know more to understand what problem you're trying to solve, but the token can be retrieved from the input and passed by other means than your form.